# If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n such that $p(x)=2^x$ for $x=1,2,3,4,5,...n+1$ . Find $p(x+2)$ and $p(x+7)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n such that $p(x)=2^x$ for $x=1,2,3,4,5,...n+1$ . Find $p(x+2)$ and $p(x+7)$.
x
I solve this problem by replacing $x$ by $x+2$  in $p(x)$,

I got $p(x+2)=2^{x+2}$ and similarly I got  $p(x+7)=2^{x+7}$

Is my method to find answer is correct? If not, please add solution to this question.

Comment: For what values of $x$ do you have to find $p(x+2)$ and $p(x+7)$?

Comment: Note:  it can't be the case that $p(x)=2^x$ for all real $x$, because $2^x$ is clearly not a polynomial (it grows much too quickly).

Comment: Taking $n=1$ we see that we want a linear polynomial, $p(x)=ax+b$, such that $p(1)=a+b=2,p(2)=2a+b=4$.  It follows that $a=2, b=0$ so $p(x)=2x$.  Just as an example of what is intended here.

Comment: The answer clearly depends on $n$. When $n=1$ you see that $p(x)=2x$ is the only polynomial that fits. When $n=2$ you want $p(x)=x^2-x+2$ et cetera.

Comment: Whatever $n$, there is one unique polynomial that fits (Lagrange interpolation theorem). That solves the question for $p(x)$. The problem is OP asked for $p(x+2)$ and $p(x+7)$ without giving the range of $x$, so there must be more to it...

Comment: What's the origin of this problem? The expected background may reflect the type of expected solution (and the tools available). I used (higher order) differences to come up with those example polynomials. [Lagrabnge interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) also quickly comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $j=1,\dots, n+1$,
$$P_n(j)=2^j=2\cdot(1+1)^{j-1}=2\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{k}=2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{j-1}{k}$$
where
$$\binom{x}{k}:=\frac{x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)}{k!}.$$
I guess that you are looking for the values of $P_n(n+2)$ and $P_n(n+7)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's a good one!